# Is there a way to execute a command in behavior from eventrigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers

The title pretty much explains the question.

I have the following in the view in a Template:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction>
            <i:InvokeCommandAction.Command>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource eventBindingHelper}" Path="DataC.SizeChangedCommand"></Binding>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction.Command>
            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igDP:LabelPresenter}}"/>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The command binding works if it's bound to the viewmodel. But i would like to bind it to a behavior and i can't seem to find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the reference to Behaviours SDK, and then you can do the following:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName="Control to trigger"}"> //Bind behaviour the the element you want to trigger
    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding parameter}"/> // Bind command and parameter to behaviour
  </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Then you can switch between the EventNames in EventTriggerBehaviour to trigger the controls as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tapped"
                    SourceName="myControlName">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding parameter}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Similar to the accepted answer but with different namespaces/class names.